Old Valve, Old Faucet. Is it compatible with new?
My house was built in the late 80s, and I'm pretty sure my kitchen faucet is original. I would like to replace it with a new one, but the fittings under there are using what looks like a pex pipe with a compression fitting, and I'm not sure a more modern braided rope type will screw onto here if I remove this nut, and I don't want to unscrew, not be able to put it back since its a compression nut, and force myself into getting a new valve without being prepared.
I can just get a new valve if I have to, but it is a bit more of a project so I just want to know ahead of time if you guys think that would be necessary here.


The fitting sizes should be the same now as before, so removing that pipe will not be hard/need changing of the valve(unless not working right).  80s grey(polybutylene) pipe does not have a good name for lasting.

3/8 Faucet supply lines, will be what you need.
The end at the shutoff valve will thread on when you remove the old line. The opposite end will need to be determined when you buy the faucet.
Often new faucet come with braided lines already marked with red and blue lines for hot and cold. Most of these have 3/8 female ends, but there is the open market to purchase stuff from countries that have non-standard equipment, so beware!
Also know that often on older shut off valves, once they are shut off they have a tendency to leak around the stem when re-opened.  Often it is a good idea to replace the shutoffs as well.

Thank you! I have some confidence now that this won't be so bad. If you check my post history I had this whole saga with my dishwasher fitting because it was some non-standard size that was impossible to get an adapter for, and I ended up just replacing the whole valve.
